# Accessing Hawtio Management Console with Openshift

Tags: openshift, hawtio

I have created a basic OpenShift Fuse instance and I am trying to login to the Hawtio console. However, I am not able to figure out what the password is. I have tried my OpenShift credentials as well as admin/admin and openshift/openshift.

Same goes for the Jenkins instance I setup as well.

Am I missing something simple?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your username and password are created when the application is created via the OpenShift web console.

[image]

Comment: That was exactly it. The issue was that the page was loading and loading without any indication of being done and I thought it was stuck so I clicked off the large. You do have to give it a second, but the image you're talking about does show up. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you create the cartridge from the command line using `rhc` then you can specify the password using the `OPENSHIFT_FUSE_ZOOKEEPER_PASSWORD` parameter.

See more details at: https://github.com/jboss-fuse/fuse-openshift-cartridge